# CSS class and id with the same name

Tags: css, class

Is there anything wrong with having a css class and id with the same name? Like .footer for the article/post's footer and #footer for the page footer.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Nope, perfectly acceptable.

A class is defined using a `.` and an ID is defined using a `#`. So as far as the browser is concerned, they're two totally separate items.

The only thing to be careful of is generating any confusion for yourself. It's probably best practise to keep the names different purely for code readability, but there's no harm in them being the same.

Comment: Ditto. And with HTML5 some elements will have the same name like footer. `footer.footer#footer` may be confusing :)

Comment: @Felipe - that'll get confusing quickly!

Comment: From the example of OP with footer and your concise explanation, my first thought was for these new elements but in fact, it should be the contrary: no more div.footer and div#footer! They'll be replaced by `footer` (targeted by, say, `body>footer` and `section footer`) and no need for class and id anymore in many cases. My bad.

Comment: "." (dot) and "#" (hash-tag) are jQuery selectors (in use for jQuery only), and there is no connection between these signs and what the browser know.

Comment: @GilEpshtain `#` is not jQuery only, anchor tags can be used in URLs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253775/css-class-and-id-with-the-same-name#comment-45935449 links to your comment directly

Comment: @GilEpshtain Also, these selectors are used in CSS. They *select* in fact what the knows about the the DOM. Just like jQuery uses JavaScript, which is an interface to the engine of the browser, to connect those selectors to the DOM.

Answer (score 15):

No, there is nothing wrong, but it might be better to use different names to not confuse other developers. It is more (human) error prone to use different names.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use same name for both **id** and **class** because both parameters have their own significance.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with having same name for class and id is code readability and maintainability. They can have the same names, the browser will render the correct CSS as classes and ids are marked differently (. for class and # for id), but an upgrade or bug fix can be a problem for the developer.

Answer (score 1):

It's completely valid but you should be aware where you put those id attributes, e.g. you can have element like this:

```
<main id="main" class="main">...</main>
```

And this is completely valid because you cannot have more `main` elements on specific page

But here's the situation that may occure some issues with duplicates

```
<section>
  <header class="header" id="header">...</header>
</section>

<article>
  <header class="header" id="header">...</header>
</article>
```

You may have multiple `header` elements on your website so you need to be sure that your id differs from each other header elements

```
<header class="header" id="unique-header">...</header>
<header class="header" id="another-unique-header">...</header>
```

With this approach you can share your styles and have two unique elements