# Validate re-enter of password javascript code require correction

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code to verify data (password) on both the fields whether it is equal.

When I enter the password in the first field and go to second field to re-enter the password I get the error cross (fa-close) at that time.

Instead I need that after I get out of second field, after that I get the error message.

HTML:

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br>
<input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" onKeyUp="checkPass(); return false;" />
<span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkPass() {
var pass1 = document.getElementById('password');
var pass2 = document.getElementById('password2');
var message = document.getElementById('confirmMessage');

var goodColor = "#fff";
var goodColored = "#087a08";
var badColor = "#fff";
var badColored = "#ed0b0b";

if(password.value == password2.value) {
  password2.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
  message.style.color = goodColored;
  message.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-check'></i>"
}
else {
  password2.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
  message.style.color = badColored;
  message.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-close'></i>"
}
}  
</script>
```

Help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: We'll need your html as well to see what is wrong. (It's probably where you're calling the function / where the event is attached)

Comment: Edited the question @Imme

Answer (score 1):

```js
function checkPass() {
 
var get_elem = document.getElementById,
pass1 = document.getElementById('password'),
pass2 = document.getElementById('password2'),
message = document.getElementById('confirmMessage'),
colors = {
goodColor: "#fff",
goodColored: "#087a08",
badColor: "#fff",
badColored:"#ed0b0b"
},
strings = {
"confirmMessage": ["good", "bad"]
};

if(password.value === password2.value && (password.value + password2.value) !== "") {
password2.style.backgroundColor = colors["goodColor"];
message.style.color = colors["goodColored"];
message.innerHTML = strings["confirmMessage"][0];
}
else if(!(password2.value === "")) {
password2.style.backgroundColor = colors["badColor"];
message.style.color = colors["badColored"];
message.innerHTML = strings["confirmMessage"][1];
}
else {
message.innerHTML = ""; 
}

}
```

```html
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" onkeyup="checkPass()" /><br>
<input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" onkeyup="checkPass()" />
<span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span>
```

How does this code work for you ? We call `checkValue()` whenever the user releases a key to deal with cases where the user types something down in the second field and then in the first field (otherwise you would have a "bad" in that case even if the user typed the same thing in both fields). Other than that modification, I didn't do much.

**Edit**: I wouldn't use the same name for both the id and class attributes of an element (`confirmMessage`), see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253775/css-class-and-id-with-the-same-name).

Comment: Good one. Thank you Sir.

Answer (score 0):

put the checkPass() call on the second password's onblur instead of the the first one or don't check if the second one is empty.

Comment: @FelipeValdes You should deal with the case I described in my answer as well.